# Identifying a large string of information containing certain data

Tags: regex

I am using an application required by this project that must utilize regular expression inputs to pre-filter data that may come in the from of html / javascript.

I have read the article decrying the use of regex filtering html; I however must in this situation.

**The issue I need help with (which seems like can not easily be explained) is finding the TAGS that contain within data_1.**

```
<TAG>
     .
     ..
     ...
     data_1
     ...
     ..
     .
</TAG>
```

I have tried many different approaches however my overall experience with regex is limited.

Example 1:

```
\<TAG.*\bdata_1\b.*?/TAG\>
```

Does not work as it actually grabs the first  that exists passing by /TAG> until it finds "data_1" then ends at the next following /TAG>

I know I am currently on the right track, I however started learning Regex about 2 days ago and am not quite there yet.

Any links, comments, advice would be most appreciated.

### Edit

It still selects all preceding TAGS.

```
***BEGIN***
<TAG>
    ....
    .....
</TAG>
<TAG>
   ...
   data_1
   ...
</TAG>
***END***
```

When it should be:

```
<TAG>
    ....
    .....
</TAG>
***BEGIN***
<TAG>
   ...
   data_1
   ...
</TAG>
***END***
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex would probably work:

```
<TAG>(?!.*?</TAG>.*?data_1).*?data_1.*?</TAG>
```

You can see the result here: http://regexr.com?2v5qt

Comment: Thank you!

You are doing (psuedo):Find the TAG, check to see if there is a respective END TAG between the START TAG and the desired data_1. If true, continue to the END TAG....If all conditions met, match!  
  
Even if that is the semi-correct line of thinking, is it flawed logic to think that regex works (deep down) similar to conditional statements? Or is that the nature of the language?  

I am reading a book that implores us to read REGEX like it is intended:  

<TAG>   should be thought of as "match '<' then match 'T' then match 'A' then match 'G' then match '>'

Comment: Yeah, your interpretation of the pattern is correct. I can't really give any useful information regarding how regex works here but the link I posted is great the experiment with regexes and here's another great resource: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to make all wildcard (`.*`) matches non-greedy (`.*?`), and you might need the "dot matches newline" switch as well `<?s>`. I also cleaned up your `<TAG>` literals

```
<?s>(<TAG>.*?\bdata_1\b.*?</TAG>)
```

You don't say which language you're using, but if you grab group number 1 of each match  you'll have your tags

Comment: Testing it out, does not seem to be producing the correct result. I'll work with it a little more before returning.